# How do I bring the border edge closer in to get rid of space within the border

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to bring the right edge of the border in so it can be closer to my text

I have tried changing the margin

html...

```
<ul id="menu" >
    <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#whatyoushouldalreadyknow">What you should already know</a></li>
    <li><a href="#javascriptandjava">JavaScript and Java</a></li>
    <li><a href="#helloworld">Hello world</a></li>
    <li><a href="#variables">Variables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#declaringvariables">Declaring variables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#variablescope">Variable Scope</a></li>
    <li><a href="#globalvariables">Global variables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#constants">Constants</a></li>
    <li><a href="#datatypes">Data types</a></li>
    <li><a href="#if...elsestatement">if...else statement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#whilestatement">while statement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#functiondeclarations">Function declarations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#reference">Reference</a></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS...

```
#menu {
  list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I expect the right edge to come in closer to text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the width of your ul in order to bring your border closer. You can increase or decrease the value as per your need

```
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
}
```

**Code**

```css
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
  <li><a href="#whatyoushouldalreadyknow">What you should already know</a></li>
  <li><a href="#javascriptandjava">JavaScript and Java</a></li>
  <li><a href="#helloworld">Hello world</a></li>
  <li><a href="#variables">Variables</a></li>
  <li><a href="#declaringvariables">Declaring variables</a></li>
  <li><a href="#variablescope">Variable Scope</a></li>
  <li><a href="#globalvariables">Global variables</a></li>
  <li><a href="#constants">Constants</a></li>
  <li><a href="#datatypes">Data types</a></li>
  <li><a href="#if...elsestatement">if...else statement</a></li>
  <li><a href="#whilestatement">while statement</a></li>
  <li><a href="#functiondeclarations">Function declarations</a></li>
  <li><a href="#reference">Reference</a></li>
</ul>
CSS...
```